# SAS Check the directory exists

Tags: sas

How can I check if directory exists and if not, it would be then: syserr <>0?, I need

```
%sysfunc(filename(fileref,&dir))
```

I need the syserr value if exists 0 if not <>0. 
thanks for help

Comment: If you Google 'SAS check if directory exists' then it returns plenty of options for you

Comment: I always have syserr=0 even I try dopen function for not existing directory. Then I have the information `The results of the operations have been set to 
      missing values.`

Comment: Why SYSERR and not some other macro variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a cleaner way of getting SAS to throw an error, but the following worked for me. The general idea is that, if the directory exists, you do something that keeps syserr set to 0; if not, you do something that throws an error.

```
%let your_path = "...";

%macro your_macro(dir);

    %let rc = %sysfunc(filename(fileref, &dir.));

    %if %sysfunc(fexist(&fileref)) %then %do;
        data _null_;
            set _null_;
        run;
    %end;
    %else %do;
        data _null_;
            set something_that_doesnt_exist;
        run;
    %end;

    %put syserr = &syserr.;

%mend your_macro; 

%your_macro(&your_path.);
```

Answer (score 6):

A cleaner method to check if a folder exists

```
%let does_it_exist=%sysfunc(fileexist(&dir));
```

This returns a value of 0 if the folder does not exist, and a value of 1 if the folder does exist.

Comment: OP needs a syserr value of 1 though, not just a macro variable of 1.

Comment: fileexist=1 can alse mean that it is a file, not a directory.